How to Automatically Adjust Data Label Positions in Excel Scatter Plot
I have an Excel scatter plot that uses slicers to filter data dynamically. I’m looking for a way to automatically adjust the positions of the data labels to avoid overlap, similar to the “best fit” label positioning option for Pie charts or the automatic label adjustment feature for scatters in Thinkcell.
The number of labels/points varies up to 50-100.

Right click on the Axis labels choose format axis. Make sure you are viewing the "Axis Options" and make sure the Bounds and Units are on Auto. If any of these are not on Auto click the reset button.

Hi, thanks for answering.
My problem is that because I have many points, labels overlap too much, and there is no 'Best fit' option in the Label position section of Format Data Labels.
I was thinking if there's a workaround it?
